# Will Google Maps expose the web API of traffic data to developers?

Tags: google-maps

I am using [predix map components](https://www.predix-ui.com/#/elements/map/px-map) to render map. And I want to add local traffic information on the map, which need the traffic data to render the traffic layer. But it looks like google maps has no such web api for developers to get JSON or XML type traffic data.

So, I really want to know if Google can provide this web api?

Comment: did you take a look at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-traffic

Comment: Yes, but that is not what I need. I want an api like this https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/samples/traffic/v2/incidents/